# C++: Changing Class Member Values From Functions

Tags: c++, class, oop, scope

I apologize for posting such a basic question, but I cant find a decent answer as to why this doesn't work, and how to get it to work.

I have simplified my issue here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
int x;
};

void otherFunction() {
A A;
cout<<"X: "<<A.x<<endl;
}

int main(){
A A;
A.x = 5;
otherFunction();

return 0;   
}
```

Do the class members become constant after constructing?

How do I expand the scope of changes done to the class?

Are structs limited in this way?

Thank you in advance for answers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers and reasons as to why it does not work. It is working now

Answer (score 3):

You are not getting the expected output because in `otherFunction()` you are creating a new object of type A for which you have not assigned a value before!

Read up on [scope of a variable](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm) in C++ to learn more

Try running the code given below, you should get the output as 5.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    int x;
};

void otherFunction(A a) {
    cout << "X: " << a.x << endl;
}

int main(){
    A a;
    a.x = 5;
    otherFunction(a);

    return 0;   
}
```

Alternatively you can do this, which is considered a good practice in OOP

```
class A{
private:
    int x;
public:
    void update(int newx){
        x = newx;
    }
    int getX(){
        return x;
    }
};

int main(){
    A a;
    a.update(5);
    cout << a.getX() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is doing what it is supposed to do.
You are creating a new object A inside the function `otherFunction`, this new object will be local to the function.
Print the the value of A.x after the call of function `otherFunction` in the main , you will see the the value of A.x has changed.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `A` in `main` is not the same as the variable `A` in `otherFunction`, so they won't have the same value.

One way to give `otherFunction` access to the value of `A` in main is to pass it in as a parameter. For example:

```
void otherFunction(A p) {
    cout<<"X: "<<p.x<<endl;
}

int main(){
    A a;
    a.x = 5;
    otherFunction(a);

    return 0;   
}
```

I have changed the names of the variables to make it a bit more clear. `a` is in main, and a *copy* of `a` is passed into `otherFunction`. That copy is called `p` in `otherFunction`. Chnages that `otherFunction` makes to `p` will not cause any change to `a`.If you want to do that, you would need to pass by reference, which is probably a topic a bit further along than you are now.